# Run python interpreter using python code, with local variables

Tags: python, debugging, pythoninterpreter

Many a times we get an error in some user defined function and want to debug it. If the error had happened in the main program, we can use the `-i` flag to preserve variables after the error. But if the error happens in a user defined function, there is no way we can access the local variables of the function. Is there a way where we can open python interpreter *through python code*, accept code from `stdin` and print output to `stdout`. Something like this:-

```
def foo():
  x = 'Inside foo()'
  run_interpreter() # Pauses for input

foo()
```

We should be able to give following input through `stdin`:-

```
print(x) # prints 'Inside foo()'
exit()   # exits interpreter and resumes other code
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do this. I don't know if there is a better way:-

```
import sys
def interpreter(vars):
    s = sys.stdin.readline().strip('\n')
    while s!= 'exit()':
        exec(s, globals(), vars)
        s = sys.stdin.readline().strip('\n')
```

I am using `sys.stdin` to read, for statements with space to be parsed properly. However, this does not provide all functionalities of interpreter. We cannot browse history using arrow keys.

This is very useful in debugging. Whenever I get an error, I call `interpreter(locals())` before that line to investigate the cause. I saved it as a sublime snippet so that it can be easily added to any python code.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a local variable of a function outside the function.

If you can to use a variable outside the function you need to declare it as a **global** Variable by Using GLOBAL.

Comment: Declaring local variables with global will unnecessarily pollute the global namespace